# Fastest way to get list of xyz coordinates between 2 points

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 Points A and B and their xyz-coordinates. I need a list of all xyz points that are on the line between those 2 points. The Bresenham's line algorithm was too slow for my case.

Example xyz for A and B:

```
p = np.array([[ 275.5, 244.2, -27.3],
           [ 153.2, 184.3,  -0.3]])
```

Expected output:

```
x3 = p[0,0] + t*(p[1,0]-p[0,0])
y3 = p[0,1] + t*(p[1,1]-p[0,1])
z3 = p[0,2] + t*(p[1,2]-p[0,2])
p3 = [x3,y3,z3]
```

There was a very fast approach for 2D:

```
def connect(ends):
    d0, d1 = np.diff(ends, axis=0)[0]
    if np.abs(d0) > np.abs(d1): 
        return np.c_[np.arange(ends[0, 0], ends[1,0] + np.sign(d0), np.sign(d0), dtype=np.int32),
                     np.arange(ends[0, 1] * np.abs(d0) + np.abs(d0)//2,
                               ends[0, 1] * np.abs(d0) + np.abs(d0)//2 + (np.abs(d0)+1) * d1, d1, dtype=np.int32) // np.abs(d0)]
    else:
        return np.c_[np.arange(ends[0, 0] * np.abs(d1) + np.abs(d1)//2,
                               ends[0, 0] * np.abs(d1) + np.abs(d1)//2 + (np.abs(d1)+1) * d0, d0, dtype=np.int32) // np.abs(d1),
                     np.arange(ends[0, 1], ends[1,1] + np.sign(d1), np.sign(d1), dtype=np.int32)]
```

Comment: Please provide a sample input and expected output

Comment: I edited my original post.

Comment: If one of the answers was what you were looking for, could you please accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to give "all" points on a line, as there are countless points. You could do that for a discrete data type like integers, though.
My answer assumes floating point numbers, as in your example.

Technically, floating point numbers are stored in a binary format with a fixed width, so they are discrete, but I will disregard that fact, as it is most likely not what you want.

As you already typed in your question, every point P on that line satisfies this equation:

P = P1 + t * (P2 - P1), 0 < t < 1

My version uses numpy broadcasting to circumvent explicit loops.

```
import numpy as np

p = np.array([[ 275.5, 244.2, -27.3],
              [ 153.2, 184.3,  -0.3]])

def connect(points, n_points):
    p1, p2 = points
    diff = p2 - p1
    t = np.linspace(0, 1, n_points+2)[1:-1]
    return p1[np.newaxis, :] + t[:, np.newaxis] * diff[np.newaxis, :]


print(connect(p, n_points=4))
# [[251.04 232.22 -21.9 ]
#  [226.58 220.24 -16.5 ]
#  [202.12 208.26 -11.1 ]
#  [177.66 196.28  -5.7 ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missunderstand something here, but couldn't you just create a function (like you already did just for one single point) and then create a list of points depending of how manny points you want?

I mean between 2 points are an infinite number of other points, so you have to either define a number or use the function directly, which describes where the points are at.

```
import numpy as np

p = np.array([[ 275.5, 244.2, -27.3],
           [ 153.2, 184.3, -0.3]])

def gen_line(p, n):

    points = []
    stepsize = 1/n
    for t in np.arange(0,1,stepsize):
        x = (p[1,0]-p[0,0])
        y = (p[1,1]-p[0,1])
        z = (p[1,2]-p[0,2])
        px = p[0,0]
        py = p[0,1]
        pz = p[0,2]
        
        x3 = px + t*x
        y3 = py + t*y
        z3 = pz + t*z
        points.append([x3,y3,z3])
    return points

# generates list of 30k points
gen_line(p, 30000)
```